# Mongodb@3.2 shell on MacOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I first ran `brew install mongodb`, which successfully completed and installed version 3.4.4.  I was then able to start the server using `brew services start mongodb`, and access the shell via running `mongo`.

Then I discovered I need mongodb version 3.2.0.  I uninstalled mongo v3.4.4 via `brew uninstall mongodb` and verified service was gone and bin files removed.

I then ran `brew search mongodb` and found mongodb@3.2 in the list, and so ran `brew install mongodb@3.2`.  This completed successfully, and I was able to start the server using `brew services start mongodb@3.2`, which is successful.  I then go to access the shell via 'mongo', or 'mongo@3.2' or 'mongo32' and none of these exist.

What should this bin file be named and why can't I find it? with v3.4.4 shell bin executable was /usr/local/bin/mongo - this file doesn't exist after installing 'mongodb@3.2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it in `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb@3.2/3.2.11/bin/` along with all the other binaries.

I don't know why it isn't symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/` like most other programs.